# How to handle two tasks using thread in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, async-await

I am getting stuck in emulator whenever i try to do display list of images which is in my server on list view and button on click for sorting images.It is listing out images one by one,at the time when i try clicking on sorting button that time my emulator is getting stuck for a while.
I want to work on that simultaneously.
I have two buttons on click function, one is for Asynctask execution with background process and another one for normal button click listener for sorting input components for reading from UI components.

```
 WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.GET_TASK, this, "Loading.....");
            wst.execute(new String[]{sampleURL});
 try {


//Extract the data…

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city_name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("room_type", room_type));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bed", no_bed));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bedrooms", no_bedrooms));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("guest_allow", guest_allowed));


            // Add your data

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                try {


//                    JSONArray jso = new JSONArray(json);
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray jso = object.getJSONArray("search_result");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "jso length" + jso.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (jso.length() != 0) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < jso.length(); i++) {
                            if (jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("city").equalsIgnoreCase(city_name)) {
                                Person resultRow = new Person();
                                resultRow.id = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_id");
                                resultRow.ProjectName = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_name");
                                resultRow.Country = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("bathrooms");

                                resultRow.city = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("city");
                                resultRow.descrip = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("price");
                                resultRow.bed = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("bed");
                                resultRow.bedrooms = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("bedrooms");
                                resultRow.guest_allow = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("guest_allow");
                                resultRow.roomtype = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("room_type");
                                resultRow.property_type = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("property_type");

                                resultRow.logo = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("property_image");

                                resultRow.user_ppty_id = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("user_property_id");
                                resultRow.check_in_time = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("check_in_time");
                                resultRow.check_out_time = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("check_out_time");
                                resultRow.host_image = jso.getJSONObject(i).getString("host_image");


                                arrayOfwebData.add(resultRow);
                                Toast.makeText(this, "counting" + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "NOT found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "NOT found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }
                ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

                Toast.makeText(this, "updated" + up, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                aa = new FancyAdapter();
                myListView.setAdapter(aa);
                up++;

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "NOT found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            //   ViewHolder aa1= new ViewHolder();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
```

and button click

```
 btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String val = (String) no_guest.getText();

                int values = Integer.parseInt(val);
                no_guest.setText("" + (values + 1));
                guest_allowed = (String) no_guest.getText();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The code seems to be executed on the UI Thread. Put all the network stuff inside the doInBackground of your AsyncTask.